# How to set active class to multiple tabs in one page onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple tabs in one page and having trouble in setting up an active class to the selected menu. It's working great if I only have one set of tab. If I click on the first tab menu, the 2nd tab menu will lose its active class. Also the fade in effect is not workin. Please help. thank you. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ko3t1723/1/).

```
$(".tabs a").click(function() {
  $(".tabs a").parent().removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

```
$(".tabs a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var p = $(this).closest('.tabs');
   var i = '#'+$(this).attr('data-tab');

   $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $(p).find('.tabInner div').hide();
   $(p).find(i).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[JFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ko3t1723/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this to fix the selection of the tabs:

```
$(".tabs a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active").fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).closest('ul').next(".tabInner").find("div").eq($(this).parent().index()).hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ko3t1723/5/)**

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast solution! I want each hidden content of the tab that about to appear to have fade in effect onclick.

Comment: This can be done in css but I prefer jquery on this project. Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, I'll see what I can do, but you're using an unconventional method for switching your tab's inner content, so I'm not sure there's an easy way to add a fade. Usually tabs in JavaScript change the display property of the tab content, where your example is using the browser's behavior of moving anchors to the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your time, I'm just using this method coz it has a lesser code lol.. and I actually dont understand jquery that much..

Comment: I just added a line that should handle the fade.